# asp.net dynamic connectionstrings

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, sqldatasource

I have an application that supports multiple companies. Each company has their own database. All company databases have an identical schema. The only difference would be the actual data that is contained therein.

There is a single customer database that contains a parent table with all of the companies, and a child table with all of the associated users. The parent company table contains a record for each company. One of the fields in the company record contains the connection string for their respective database.

When a user logs in, the application creates a company objects that includes the connection string to their database and puts it into a session variable. When each page loads, there is a method that is fired that loops through all of the SQLDatasource controls and sets the connection string to the one in the session variable.

There is one UI that is used for all companies.

In my web.config file I have a common connectionstring to my development database (also with an identical schema) that I use during development to configure my SQLDatasources, with the intention that at run time the data source will point to the customers' database connection.

Everytime a page load occurs and the connection string is set to something other than what is in the web.config file, it forces a rebind of the grid and viewstate is lost.

Am I just dynamically setting the connection string incorrectly, or what?

Thanks,
Marty

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the connection strings in `Page_Init` instead of `Page_Load`.